# Why is the default line length in the KOMA scrreprt documentclass longer than recommended?

Tags: margins, koma-script, typography

When using the documentclass `scrreprt` (KOMA scripts) with the default parameters (`a4paper`, `11pt`, `DIV10`), I observe line lengths between 81 and 85 characters (including spaces and punctuation, 78 to 85 without the package microtype). This is noticeably longer than the usually considered optimal lengths of 60 to 70 characters, also described as such in the KOMA manual. The manual also puts an (absolute) upper limit of 80 characters that should not be exceeded.

Thus my question: Am I doing something wrong? Or is this just the reality of the A4 paper size  colliding with the theory of optimal line length?

Here, the rather trivial MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrreprt}  
\begin{document}  
Suspendisse vel felis. Ut lorem lorem, interdum eu, tincidunt sit amet, laoreet vitae, arcu. Aenean faucibus pede eu ante. Praesent enim elit, rutrum at, molestie non, nonummy vel, nisl. Ut lectus eros, malesuada sit amet, fermentum eu, sodales cursus, magna. Donec eu purus. Quisque vehicula, urna sed ultricies auctor, pede lorem egestas dui, et convallis elit erat sed nulla. Donec luctus. Curabitur et nunc. Aliquam dolor odio, commodo pretium, ultricies non, pharetra in, velit. Integer arcu est, nonummy in, fermentum faucibus, egestas vel, odio.
Sed commodo posuere pede. Mauris ut est. Ut quis purus. Sed ac odio. Sed vehicula hendrerit sem. Duis non odio. Morbi ut dui. Sed accumsan risus eget odio. In hac ha- bitasse platea dictumst. Pellentesque non elit. Fusce sed justo eu urna porta tincidunt. Mauris felis odio, sollicitudin sed, volutpat a, ornare ac, erat. Morbi quis dolor. Donec pellentesque, erat ac sagittis semper, nunc dui lobortis purus, quis congue purus metus ultricies tellus. Proin et quam. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per co- nubia nostra, per inceptos hymenaeos. Praesent sapien turpis, fermentum vel, eleifend faucibus, vehicula eu, lacus.  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you load any other font packages? Please add a MWE.

Answer (score 6):

[Someone else will probably point out that this is not 'real' question. I still think a few helpful, if possibly subjective, things can be said]

You're not doing anything 'wrong'. Keep in mind that there isn't *the* perfect line length for all purposes, or for all readers. There's people used to reading A4, MS Word, Arial 10 on 18 pt, 1-inch-margin documents with 100 chars per line on a daily basis as part of their jobs (think of people reading student papers). After a few years or so, these people will not necessarily find that difficult to read.

You're right, though: when you're after a 65 chars-per-line line, and want to keep type size around 12pt -- then A4 and letter paper are too wide, unless you're using a typeface of  above-average width (which may itself reduce readability), or a rather narrow measure.

What I use, with usual 'workhorse' typefaces like Minion, Palatino, Miller or Scala, is `DIV9` and `12pt` (on 15 or 16pt) for pretty much all purposes. Over the years I found that to be the most pleasing and practical solution, particularly as the left and right margins are wide enough to each accommodate a thumb holding the paper without covering the text. Unless I'm explicitly asked to do otherwise.

```
\documentclass[DIV9,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{leading}
\leading{16pt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgschola}

\begin{document}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

This yields an average line length of about 70 chars. Unless you're using more condensed typefaces like Minion or Times New Roman, in which case line length is around 80.

PS: when you're told to use A4 paper, a particular typeface at a particular size and leading, and a particular margin size, you may still be free to typeset as a two-column (!) document.